# How to download multiple files with OkHttp?

Tags: android, okhttp

I need to download multiple files with OkHttp libarary. And after all downloads are finished I need to inform user.

I know how to download one file with OkHttp. Here is code:

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();
okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new okhttp3.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(okhttp3.Call call, IOException e) {
                Log.d("TAG", "download file fail: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(okhttp3.Call call, okhttp3.Response response) throws IOException {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
               //I have response data of downloaded file
            }
          }
        });
```

How I can dowload all files, not just one?

Comment: what about making multiple requests?

Answer (score 4):

I'll just throw an RxJava / Kotlin example in here...

```
Observable.from(urls)
   .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
   .map { url ->
       val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
       okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute()
   }
   .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
   .subscribe { responses -> 
       // responses: List<Response> - do something with it
       // nothify User (we're on the UI thread here)
   }, { error ->
       // handle the error
   }
```

Not only is this concise but also does it handle errors & thread synchronization

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have a list with URLs to download the files.

```
String[] urls = //;
```

for every url make a request.

```
for (String url : urls) {
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();
Response response = okHttpClient.newCall(request);
// do something with the response

}
```

Comment: Okey, I should mention that I tried for loop, but it does not work.

Comment: @Zookey I changed my answer

Comment: What is difference between old answer and this updated? I think for loop wont work because everything happens in background and you lose control of which file is downloaded.